# How can I tell that Samsung Galaxy Tab cannot place phone calls?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to programatically know that Samsung Galaxy Tab cannot place phone calls. When I call `telephonyManager.getPhoneType()` it returns `PHONE_TYPE_CDMA`. When I call `telephonyManager.getLine1Number()` it returns a valid phone number.

However, there's no dialer.

Comment: Thats odd, it should be `PHONE_TYPE_NONE`.
Have you tried using other stuff like `getCallState()` or `getSimState()` to see if it returns something wierd that you could use.

Comment: Does this device perchance have service through a mobile network, but no voice plan?

Comment: Yes, that's right. For instance I can do SMS messaging and 3G data.

Comment: Hello i am Facing Same Problem Like You i use Following Code to Detect That my Android Device Can not Make Call Using ACTION_CALL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if there are any matches on an `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL` `Intent`. If there are none, that would be a reasonable test. I have not tried this on my Tab yet, so I have no idea if this trick will work.

Bear in mind that Android devices are supposed to be phones. I have no idea why Google let the Tab pass the compatibility tests without a dialer. The next version of Android should have more official non-phone support (for tablets and TVs), and so there will hopefully be a better solution.

Comment: Perhaps it will be able to call later on and we still dont know about it?

Comment: @blindstuff: I know they yanked the dialer out late. Not sure why, though. For all I know, `ACTION_CALL` still works, and anybody can create a replacement dialer for it.

Comment: That worked. It turns out they do return a ResolveInfo for ACTION_DIAL, namely com.android.phone.EmptyDialActivity. For kicks I started the ACTION_DIAL activity and it showed a dialog "Cannot make or take a call using Galaxy-Tab.". ACTION_CALL returns an empty list, so I'll use that.  Thanks!

Comment: It turns out I was not passing a phone number with the ACTION_CALL intent and it was always returning an empty list. Now it always returns an activity, so I can't use that wither. For now I have to hack it and check if the name is com.android.phone.EmptyDialActivity. However, this is far from a general solution, since it's probably pretty Galaxy-Tab specific.

Comment: @dhaag23: Yeah, that's interesting. That class is not in the Android 2.2 source code, which means either it's from a private internal branch in Android or Samsung put it in the `com.android` package when they should not have. I suspect that the "all Market-compatible devices are phones" limit is why this hack is in there. Hope that 3.0 clears up detecting whether a device is a phone, and live with your `EmptyDialActivity`-detecting hack for now.